# How to animate a dot to box transformation animation in android?

Tags: java, android, animation

initially, there will be dot,on click of a button,the dot must be transformed into a rectangular box.

this is the series of events to take place when a button is clicked

[image: this is the series of events to take place when a button is clicked]

help is appreciated.thanks

Comment: Please post the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple approach

1. generate a rectangular box via drawable if its simple or use a ImageView with a image as source.

   If its a drawable, then set this drawable to the view.

   1. set onclicklistener to the view via

   view..setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
       {

   ```
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v)
       {
           Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(YourActivity.this, R.anim.dot2square);
           //v.setAnimation(anim);
           v.startAnimation(anim);
       }
   });
   ```

   1. last step.

add this piece of code for your dot to box animation in a file (dot2square.xml) in res/anim/ folder.

```
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="1000"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:fromXScale="0.1"
android:fromYScale="0.1"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
android:toXScale="1"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:toYScale="1" >
</scale>
```

Summary:
defining animation in the xml format that android provides.
then setting the animation to the view and starting